# OpenLayers 4 variable icon rotation

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I have a variety of data sources that I'm reading from an API.
This data has a number of properties relative to the API endpoint but all share some common ones, namely:

- Easting
- Northing
- Rotation
- Name

From this I generate GeoJSON objects (they are all Point features, and I convert the Easting/Northing into lat/Long) and render each data source on my map through some common code:

```
let vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(featureCollection)
    }),
    style: style
});

this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

This gets the Points on my map, and can I can style them by creating custom styles, I'm using images (.png) as the point marker.

But what I need to do is rotate the marker based on the Rotation attribute of the data, and I have no idea how to do that.

Each data point from the API will have its own rotation - they aren't all rotated be the same degree.

This system was initially using `this.map.addOverlay(overlay)` to add each point, which was fine in testing but really doesn't scale up that well, as it took too longer to render them. At present my largest data set is just shy of 7000 data points.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a style function instead of a static style: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction

Thus you can style each feature calculating a rotation based on its attributes.

Comment: Marked as correct, although not tested it. As my rotation data was seemingly random numbers I couldn't do what i wanted anyway. From the docs: `A function that takes an ol.Feature and a {number} representing the view's resolution. The function should return a ol.style.Style or an array of them. This way e.g. a vector layer can be styled.`

Answer (score 0):

Do to the lack of response and nothing apparent in the documentation I have come to the conclusion that you can't do this... which is a shame.

So I changed tack, and based on this SO QA [Rotating polygon in OpenLayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736121/rotating-polygon-in-openlayers-3) I wrote a wrapper to convert my point features into Polygons with the actual location as the center point. I could then rotate the polygon.

Not ideal, and it turned out my rotation data was totally impenetrable anyway - its defined as an Angle but its not in either degrees or radians.